# field value (for hint/usability) show without having it be a field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that has values prefilled for usability/hints - unfortunately one of these fields validated against a servlet that I don't have access to.

So when I use:

```
<input type="text" class="promocode" name="LLN" id="promo1" value="Enter promotion code" maxlength="40"  title="Promotion Code 1" onfocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;">
```

This doesn't work, because the validation servlet sees that the field has been filled, and it then runs it through the validation process and returns an error (because it's not the correct format).

I know if I had some js to work with I could have it only run validation against values not the default.

But in this case, I'm not sure how to show the form field hints without filling in a value.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be adding an `<span>` on top of your input and hiding it when the input got the focus. This would not even touch the input.
You can position span using relative/absolute.
I hope you like this solution

HTML

```
<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="text" id="theInput" />
  <span id="theSpan">Please fill this input!</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .inputContainer{position:relative;}
 #theSpan{position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
```

JS

```
    $('#theInput').focus(function(){
        $('#theSPan').hide()
    });
  $('#theInput').blur(function(){
       if($(this).val()==''){ $('#theSPan').show()}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser support requirements, consider using the [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) attribute. I believe there are javascript plugins that will apply placeholder support to those browsers that don't support it natively.

Comment: I've been looking at the plugins - I am using placeholder, but most of the plugins just write placeholder to the value or place a span over the field. So I still run into the validation issue for value and then I'm not in love with the span positioned over the field. I was thinking of clearing the value on form submit, but that's not going to work because of various functionality tied to the submit.

Comment: Setting the value for the placeholder is less than ideal -- you get weird behavior with Firefox when you reload the page. I would recommend a library that uses a generated span rather than setting the value. Setting the value also breaks down when working with password fields.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to clear only the default values (the hint) on submit, but not clear any other values..thoughts?

Comment: You could capture the page submission event and loop through every field in the form, checking to see if the field's value attribute is different than is DOM `value` property. If they are different, you know it isn't one of the default values, and it should be submitted. Otherwise, set `disabled` to true, preventing the field from being a  [successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). If you need an example, let me know and I can whip one up.